# Where to put calculations logic (model, resource) and the best way to do it

Tags: php, html, laravel, model, controller

I have a controller method to view all existing tours. (Controller calls a service method, which returns model with all relationships). As a return from the controller I use resource and Laravel `->paginate()` function.

Everything works cool, but here is my question.

In the service method I need to go throw for example 5 tours and calculate price for them. How can I do it correctly? I mean, I can calculate this price and create a new array with my necessary and calculated data. But probably I won't have my `paginate()`.

So what is the best way to go throw returned models, calculate something and return same data but with my additional calculations.

I had an idea to use resource and write the calculation logic in it, but I think it should not be stored in resource.

So please, any advice (maybe with code example).

Comment: What is this price calculated from? The data from the model (and any related models)? If so, a method on the model that returns the calculated data seems the way to go.

Comment: @El_Vanja Yep, also i've read about this idea. But the price is calculated from different models and also including some request data from controller.

Comment: Different as in unrelated? As for the request params, they can become method params, so no issue there.